# Trying to build tailwind card with blur text in bottom

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a card tailwind css with a background image and a blurred lower part of the card
Above this blurred area, I would like to display a label.

The expected result is this:

[image]

So far I have this rendering:

[image]

On the blurred area, it seems that there is like a white or gray inner border, I don't know why.
This is my code :

```
    <div class="w-80 h-52 relative mx-0 my-auto rounded-2xl overflow-hidden">
    <div class="w-full h-full bg-cover bg-center" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.8), rgba(0,0,0,0)), url(' + url + ')' }">
        <div class="absolute w-full h-16 bottom-0 z-10 flex text-center justify-center items-center backdrop-blur-sm overflow-hidden">
            <span class="text-2xl text-white font-nunito">{{ label }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Can you please create a minimal reproducible example? Creating it in Tailwind Play seems fine: https://play.tailwindcss.com/9rEtLBZSqT